# Compare element by element from two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I'd like to compare element by element from two `data.frame` called `df1` and `df2`. From they, I'd like to build a new `data.frame` called `out`. If the elements are equals, then the element in `out` is `1`, otherwise is `0`.

## MWE

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(Q1 = sample(letters[1:5], 2, replace = TRUE), 
                 Q2 = sample(letters[1:5], 2, replace = TRUE))    
set.seed(2)
df2 <-  data.frame(Q1 = sample(letters[1:5], 2, replace = TRUE), 
                   Q2 = sample(letters[1:5], 2, replace = TRUE))
```

## Expected output

```
out <- data.frame(Q1 = c(0, 0), Q2 = c(1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the datasets are created with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating the `data.frame` - `factor` makes it difficult as the attributes would create difficulty in doing the comparison)

```
+(df1 == df2)
```

---

Or if it is `factor` convert to `character` columns with `type.convert`

```
+(type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE) == type.convert(df2, as.is = TRUE))
```

Or make use of `matrix` hack way of changing to `character`

```
+(as.matrix(df1) == as.matrix(df2))
```

Comment: isn't there a 1 missing compared to the desired output?

Comment: @bretauv  I think it could be the output from a different set.seed.  In the recent R version, `sample` changed and if they use a different setting, values would be different